# How to use jQuery autocomplete with json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

I'm learning Ajax and jQuery and trying to use json file as data source. I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete widget to help user select one option. I know I'm terribly off the track.

My json file:

```
[
    {"iata":"AAC", "name":"El Arish"},
    {"iata":"AAE", "name":"Annabah"},
    {"iata":"AAF", "name":"Apalachicola"},
    {"iata":"AAG", "name":"Arapoti"},
    {"iata":"AAH", "name":"Aachen"},
    {"iata":"AAI", "name":"Arraias"},
    {"iata":"AAJ", "name":"Awaradam"},
    {"iata":"AAK", "name":"Buariki"},
    {"iata":"AAL", "name":"Aalborg"},
    {"iata":"AAM", "name":"Malamala"},
    {"iata":"AAN", "name":"Al Ain"}
]
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var searchField = $('#search').val();
            var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
            $.getJSON("beta.json", function (data) {
                var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    if ((val.iata.search(myExp) !== -1) ||
                            (val.name.search(myExp) !== -1)) {
                        output += '<li>';
                        output += '<h2>' + val.iata + '</h2>';
                        output += '<p>' + val.name + '</p>';
                        output += '</li>';
                    }
                });
                output += '</ul>';
                $('#update').html(output);
            });
            )
            });
        }    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed some syntax errors and then wrote up this example to really get you jump started.

```js
$( function() {
 $.getJSON("http://neil.computer/stack/beta.json", function(data) {
  autoComplete = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
   autoComplete.push(data[i].name + ", " + data[i].iata);
  }
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: autoComplete
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like to select one of the option. Now it is just giving me an unordered list list when I search and does not allow me to select one of the option. Thats why I select autocomplete widget.

Answer (score 2):

You can push `html` to an array at `request`, pass array to `response`, at `.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem` create an `<li>` element with `html` set to second argument `item`, `.value` property, which should be `html` set within `request` and passed to `response`; append `<li>` to first argument `ul`, `return` `ul` from `._renderItem`

```
  var elem = $("#search");
  $.ajaxSetup({
    context: elem
  });
  elem.autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("beta.json")
          .then(function success(data) {
            var searchField = elem.val();
            var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
            var res = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
              if ((val.iata.search(myExp) !== -1) ||
                (val.name.search(myExp) !== -1)) {
                res.push("<h2>" + val.iata + "</h2>" + "<p>" + val.name + "</p>")
              }
            });
            response(res);

          }, function error(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown) // log `$.ajax` errors
          })
      }
    })
    .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      return $("<li>", {
        html: item.value
      }).appendTo(ul)

  };
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wr1wg5df/11/